# Force a APEX_MAIL to send a Date: message header?

Tags: oracle-apex

```
In oracle apex, I am using APEX_MAIL.SEND function to send mail. The mail is sent correctly, however, automatically, another mail arrives with the following information:

Your message WAS SUCCESSFULLY RELAYED to:
  <account@domain.net>

This delivery report was generated by the program amavisd-new at host deneb.catsa.net. Our internal reference code for your message is 35575-18/W5fQAUCbp11y

INVALID HEADER: MISSING REQUIRED HEADER FIELD
Missing required header field: "Date"
Return-Path: <crvictor@catsa.net>
From: crvictor@catsa.net
Message ID: <D6084414148F0763E053020010AC1735@172.16.0.15>
Subject: =?utf-8?B?QXByb2JhY2nDs24gZGUgc29saWNpdHVkICMxNDg1NSBw?=
  =?utf-8?B?b3IgQ1JWSUNUT1I=?=

MISSING REQUIRED HEADER FIELD
```

The RFC 5322 document specifies rules for forming internet messages.
Section '3.6. Field Definitions' specifies that certain header fields
are required (origination date field and the "From:" originator field).
How can I send the date header using this function?
Note: I don't want to use pl/sql's utl_smtp

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: La sentencia APEX_MAIL.SEND no envía como parte de sus parámetros la fecha, dato obligatorio para el encabezado de los correos.  El administrador de correo envía correctamente, sin embargo, envía otro correo indicando ese error.